# "cacheInternal" is not recognized after KB4024848 installation

Tags: asp.net

I am taking over an ASP.NET MVC application from someone who left. The application was developed using .NET Framework4.
Everything was working fine, until an automatic security update was pushed to the system.
Basically, the following statement now throws a NULL exception after the push of KB4024848:

object obj = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetProperty("CacheInternal",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null,null);

Looks like the key string "cacheInternal" is not recognized anymore. 
Rollback of KB4024848 would make the statement work again.
Any idea about this issue, as well as what could be an alternative solution to get the same object value? (This statement is part of a section of code trying to get a list of active sessions, using InProcSessionState.)
Your solution to this question will be greatly appreciated, since we have been spending quite sometime to work on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpRuntime CacheInternal NULL reference exception while reading user sessions (Reflection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040537/httpruntime-cacheinternal-null-reference-exception-while-reading-user-sessions)