# get all active sessions asp.net core 2

Tags: session, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to get all active sessions, actually, I want to show logged in users.
I visited this page [Get a list of all active sessions in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854176/get-a-list-of-all-active-sessions-in-asp-net) but it does not work for me. It seems it does not work in Asp.Net core 2.

Comment: That question is from 2012 and is referencing ASP.NET (ASP.NET Core did not exist at the time). As such, it has no relevance here. Regardless, that was more of a hack than an actual solution. Long and short, there's no built-in way to get all logged in users, since the user's state of being logged in or not is stored client-side as a cookie, not at the server. You'll need to keep an external log or record of logins you can reference later for this info, but that's all on you.

Comment: I know that, but, they both have something in common. So you mean I should save users information in a static class or a database and something like these?